# How to setup Nokogiri and a proxy from ProxyMesh

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, proxy

I am currently getting the following error when trying to use a proxy I got from ProxyMesh:

```
407 proxy authorization required
```

I'm using Nokogiri and a rotating set of agents to access a URL.. The code looks like:

```
url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(address, :proxy => 'http://555.XXX.2.203:XXXXX', 
"User-Agent" => "#{aliases[0]}"))
```

There is a setup needed in my app where I pass in my user and password, but they don't have a page explaining it for Ruby.. Here is the example in Python if anyone can translate??

```
>>> import requests
>>> auth = requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
>>> proxies = {'http': 'http://aa-aa.proxymesh.com:12345'}
>>> response = requests.get('http://example.com', proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
```

Here is the page on ProxyMesh with the other languages.. 
[ProxyMesh Explained](https://proxymesh.com/http-client-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you didn't set up the IP address in the ProxyMesh dashboard. I had the same error as yours and it fixed when I did that.